# Notepad++ highlight occurrences between tags

Tags: regex, search, notepad++

I want to copy all occurrences of a particular key in a .reg file.
e.g.

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\PatchInstaller\201506291458.15] 
"Title 1"="HotFix 2.3" <br/>"Notes"=""  

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\PatchInstaller\201506291458.38]
"Title 1"="HotFix 2.4"  <br/>"Notes"=""

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\PatchInstaller\201506291459.1]
"Title 1"="HotFix 2.5"  <br/>"Notes"=""
```

Though `tle 1"="(.*)"` finds what I want, I need to exclude the surrounding  quotes from being highlighted.

Comment: Are you looking for `Title 1"="\K[^"]+`?

Comment: Yes. Can you please put this as an answer. I looked at other search and replace solutions here but couldn't reframe them for my situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To only match the characters other than a  double quote after `Title 1"="`, you can use the negated character class `[^"]+` and use the `\K` operator before it:

```
Title 1"="\K[^"]+
```

[image]

The `\K` operator just omits the whole text matched so far. So, the match text only contains what is matched with `[^"]+`.